# Macro to insert 19 rows every nth row?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to insert 19 rows every 58 rows. This macro inserts one single row and I can't seem to get it to insert 19.

```
Sub Insert58()
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range("A3")
    While rng.Value <> ""
        rng.Offset(58).EntireRow.Insert
        Set rng = rng.Offset(59)
    Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `rng.Offset(58).resize(19).EntireRow.Insert`

Comment: For whatever reason, using this line of code, it adds 19 new rows only once, but doesn't keep repeating. Any idea why?

Comment: Because your while clause is no longer true.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I'm new to vba, do you know how I'd fix it?

Comment: once you have inserted 19 rows, you want to skip 77 rows *(58+19)*

Answer (score 1):

Jeff,

Give this a try:

```
Sub Insert58_v2()
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range("A3")
    While rng.Value <> ""
        rng.Offset(58).Resize(19).EntireRow.Insert
        Set rng = rng.Offset(77)
    Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Gimp's answer is of course editable:

`Set rng = Range("A3")` is the start cell

`rng.Offset(58)` is 'after how many each rows'

`Resize(19)` is how many rows to insert

`Set rng = rng.Offset(77)` should be a sum of both rows+inserted